# Google chart table formatting cell as percentage

Tags: charts, formatting, cell, google-apps, percentage

I am trying to format a cell in a google chart table as a percentage field.

For a column it works with :

```
var flow_format2 = new google.visualization.NumberFormat( {suffix: '%', negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true, fractionDigits: 0} );
```

But as far as I can read there is no possibility for a row, therefore I would like to do it on cell level - is that possible?

Is it with `setProperty` I need to do it and what is the formatting syntax.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `formatValue` method of [`NumberFormat`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat) to get the formatted string
rather than applying to the entire column

then you can manually `setFormattedValue` on the DataTable cell
to change the color, use `setProperty` to change the cell's `'style'` property
the chart must be drawn afterwards

--or--

when the chart's `'ready'` event fires, you can change the cell value using the DOM
the `Table` chart produces a normal set of html `<table>` tags

following is a working snippet, demonstrating both approaches...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        {label: 'Name', type: 'string'},
        {label: 'Amount', type: 'number'},
      ],
      rows: [
        {c:[{v: 'Adam'}, {v: -1201}]},
        {c:[{v: 'Mike'}, {v: 2235}]},
        {c:[{v: 'Stephen'}, {v: -5222}]},
        {c:[{v: 'Victor'}, {v: 1288}]},
        {c:[{v: 'Wes'}, {v: -6753}]}
      ]
    });

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var tableChart = new google.visualization.Table(container);

    var patternFormat = {
      suffix: '%',
      negativeColor: '#FF0000',
      negativeParens: true,
      fractionDigits: 0
    };

    // create the formatter
    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(patternFormat);

    // format cell - first row
    dataTable.setFormattedValue(0, 1, formatter.formatValue(dataTable.getValue(0, 1)));
    if (dataTable.getValue(0, 1) < 0) {
      dataTable.setProperty(0, 1, 'style', 'color: ' + patternFormat.negativeColor + ';');
    }

    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(tableChart, 'ready', function () {

      // format cell via DOM - third row
      var tableCell = container.getElementsByTagName('TR')[3].cells[1];
      tableCell.innerHTML = formatter.formatValue(dataTable.getValue(2, 1));
      if (dataTable.getValue(2, 1) < 0) {
        tableCell.style.color = patternFormat.negativeColor;
      }

    });

    tableChart.draw(dataTable, {
      allowHtml: true
    });
  },
  packages: ['table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help WhiteHat it works perfect ;-)